# how to automatically break the lua program at the error line

Tags: zerobrane

I use my own interpreter to run the lua program and debug with zerobrane. If the interpreter encounters an error, how to let the debugger break at the error line?

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism in Lua that allows to catch run-time errors. There was a call to `debug.traceback` function in Lua 5.1, but it's no longer called in Lua 5.2+. If you have your own error handling, you can call `require("mobdebug").pause()`, which will request ZeroBrane Studio debugger to stop on the next executable Lua line, which will allow you at least to see the stack trace and the location of the error, but this is probably all you can do. You can also try to assign `debug.traceback` to the function that calls `pause`, but, again, this will only work in Lua 5.1.

For example, try running the following script from the IDE:

```
require("mobdebug").start()
debug.traceback = function(...)
  print("traceback", ...)
  require("mobdebug").pause()
end
a()
print("done") -- it will never get here
```

If you save it into `on-error.lua` file and run, you should see the execution stopped on line 5 (after the `pause()`) call with the following message:

```
traceback   on-error.lua:6: attempt to call global 'a' (a nil value)    2
```

Comment: I have created an error handing function on the host application (c++). But I cannot pause the lua code by using mobdebug.pause() from the c++ side. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @Mixwind, I'm not sure what you mean by "from the c++ side", but if this means that `mobdebug.pause()` is called from your c++ code, then it's not likely to work, as the debug hook is set on the executed Lua code, so it will have to run some Lua code to "pause" it.

Comment: I found a way. From c++ side I use luaL_dostring to call mobdebug.pause() and do another string like "file=‘c:/test.lua' line=3". Then I modify the debugger in zerobrane to parse the command and activate the file.

Comment: Yes, this should work; thank you for sharing! It may be worth adding file/line parameters to `pause()`, so it can be set up internally (although it should stop on the next Lua command anyway).

Comment: I got another issue. If I raise an error in a C function, I have to find the lua_Debug information at a higher stack level. Then I use the trick to let zerobrane activate the lua file. But this time I can't get the value of any local variable from zerobrane.  How can I modify the debugger to show them?

Comment: You should be able to see the variables in the stack window (at any frame level).

Comment: But I want to show the value when the user hovers the mouse on a variable.

Comment: At first I thought you just want to get local variables from a different call frame, but if you want to explore them after an error, I don't think this is going to work, as the Lua state can't provide that information at that time (after the error is propagated and not captured with a pcall or coroutine resume). I used to have an (incomplete) workaround using debug.traceback handling, but it was only available in Lua 5.1.

Comment: Actually, I am using Lua 5.1 and the pcall to capture the error and a traceback function for error handling. Now I can use zerobrane to explore the local variables after a error occurs in a Lua function. But I can't do the same thing for a C function. Maybe it is in a different stack level?